# Spring eureka dashboard returns XML on wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy my eureka-service at wildfly, but when i try to access the dashboard i get the following xml as response:

```
<com.netflix.eureka.util.StatusInfo>
<generalStats>
<environment>test</environment>
<num-of-cpus>4</num-of-cpus>
<total-avail-memory>3525mb</total-avail-memory>
<current-memory-usage>736mb (20%)</current-memory-usage>
<server-uptime>00:01</server-uptime>
</generalStats>
<applicationStats>
<registered-replicas>http://localhost:8761/eureka/</registered-replicas>
<available-replicas/>
<unavailable-replicas>http://localhost:8761/eureka/,</unavailable-replicas>
</applicationStats>
<instanceInfo>
<instanceId>note:eureka-service:8761</instanceId>
<hostName>note</hostName>
<app>EUREKA-SERVICE</app>
<ipAddr>192.168.1.36</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">8761</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>0</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>0</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>0</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
<homePageUrl>http://note:8761/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://note:8761/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://note:8761/health</healthCheckUrl>
<vipAddress>eureka-service</vipAddress>
<secureVipAddress>eureka-service</secureVipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1491796603178</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1491796615476</lastDirtyTimestamp>
</instanceInfo>
</com.netflix.eureka.util.StatusInfo>
```

Does anyone know how to get dashboard deploying at wildfly?

Answer (score 4):

In my case the other two solutions didn't help.

I searched for hours and found the solution while debugging the spring code.
The viewResolver for freemarker did not found the templates in *spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar*.

In fact i only had to set one simple property to get the things done:

**spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access=false**

Comment: i put this property but it's not work again and in come up with xml ui

Comment: this property worked for me with spring boot version 2.0.4.RELEASE. It worked like charm. How did you come to know this @Benjamin Schüller ?

Comment: Just in case anyone needs clarification: this solution works because by default, eureka searches for the templates (that create that dashboard page) in a *templates* folder on the classpath. Since, on an application server, there might be more than one jars that have that folder (and they wouldn't contain the template that Eureka is searching for), an error would be thrown up. The above solution ensures that Eureka doesn't search other jars for the *templates* folder, but only its own jar

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I had an empty folder, src/main/resources/templates. When this folder exists, FreeMarkerView cannot see the embedded templates contained in spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server. I don't remember where this folder originated but I suspect it is in the online sample. Deleting it corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>eureka</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This was the pom.xml of the auto generated https://start.spring.io/ page. It turns out, that I had to change the version number of the spring-boot-starter-parent artifact to a lower version, in order to display the eureka dashboard correctly.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounted this problem recently. At last, I found it was caused by the bad freemarker jar, I removed the freemarker jar from my local maven repos and re-downloaded it again, then it was solved.