# Spring Boot: Eureka dashboard comes up as xml when deployed as a war on jBoss

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

The usual Eureka dashboard is something like:

[image]

But mine appears as:

[image]

The problem is that the same war, when run as an executable war works perfectly fine (the spring-boot-maven-plugin creates both a deployable war, and an executable one), but when deployed as war in **jBoss 6.4 EPA**, it shows the dashboard as xml (I'll detail the differences in property files for jBoss below)

Here's the **pom**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mine.naming</groupId>
    <artifactId>NamingServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>NamingServer</name>
    <description>GRS 4.0 Naming Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here's the Application class:

```
package com.tcs.naming.UtxNamingServer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class NamingServerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(NamingServerApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Here's the **application.properties** used while deploying as a jar:

```
spring.application.name=naming-server
server.contextPath=/naming-server

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Now, some changes are required to deploy the war (without the tomcat dependencies) in jBoss. Here's the **application.properties** file when deploying in jBoss:

```
spring.application.name=naming-server
server.servlet-path=/*

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Here's the **jboss-web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>/naming-server</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Here's the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.mine.naming-server" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The **jax-rs** subsystem is excluded because otherwise there is a jar clash between my Jersey implementation included in Eureka and jBoss's RESTEasy implementation. The module above is just there to make the **application.properties** file available to the application (and its getting picked up, I confirmed)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Eureka searches for the **freemarker (`.ftl`) templates** (that are used for creating the dashboard page) in a `templates` folder on the classpath. Since, on an application server, there might be more than one jars that have that folder (and they wouldn't contain the template that Eureka is searching for), an error would be thrown up.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370114/443259), the solution is to add the following property to application.properties so that Eureka doesn't search other jars for the `templates` folder

```
spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access=false
```